# NGINX Occasionally Serving Wrong Block

Tags: nginx, mod-pagespeed

I am having the strangest problem in the world and it's only been recently... I also think that it may have something to do with the Pagespeed module, but I can't be sure.

Anyway when I curl my website on HTTPS ex: https://example.com

Sometimes it loads correctly, but other times it will serve the contents of the port 80 server block (of which is a 307 redirect back to the https://)

This is causing redirect loop errors occasionally on Google Chrome.

It seems totally random whether it will serve the appropriate contents or serve the port 80 server block which just drives me crazy.

I know it's serving the listen to 80 server block because when I changed the redirect on that block to a 307 or 302 it will return that error or vice versa.

I have never had an error like this in my life - it is exceptionally strange.

Any thoughts as to how to debug this?

I have been using NGINX for years, and I have never seen this before.

Comment: Do you have another reverse proxy server in front of nginx?

Comment: Can you add your Nginx config?

Comment: @MichaelHampton no

Comment: @dkokmadis okay please look

Comment: I don't see any nginx config here?